# Is there any implementation of Nesterov's paper: Gradient methods for minimizing composite functions

Tags: convex-optimization

I worked on a method based on this paper, "Gradient methods for minimizing composite functions". But unfortunately, every time I code it doesn't work. Even I investigate inequalities of the paper numerically, but I couldn't figure out what's the problem. Is there any matlab implementation of the paper available? I search the internet but I didn't find any thing? In my work, I don't need to find Lipschitz constant as it did in paper.

Comment: Here's a paper where they use Nesterov's method to solve cone complementarity problem at each time step to simulate many-rigid-body dynamics. Their solver should be implemented in their "chrono" software package (projectchrono.org). Their implementation is in C++, not matlab. http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2735627

Comment: Thank you but I can't find any code regarding this. Could you point to a code?

Comment: Also, it is the simpler nesterov method, APG with adaptive restart and a fall back strategy based on their paper.

Comment: It's a fairly large project, and the solver is buried pretty deep in there. Here's a link to their site though: http://projectchrono.org/